# How to return from function if argument is not supplied using Exception

Tags: python

To make sure the function is passed a correct argument I always start a function definition with if statement to check the argument for validity:

```
def func(arg=None):
    if not isinstance(arg, int): return
    return arg+2

func('a')
print 'this is the end line'
```

While it works for me well, I wonder if there is more Pythonic way of doing it.
I do like the `Exception` approach. But I don't want the exception to crash the entire process just because of one of the arguments was not supplied or if it is not what the function expects:

```
def func(arg=None):
    if not isinstance(arg, int):
        raise ValueError('expected integer. receivd: %s instead'%type(arg))
    return arg+2



func('a')
print 'this is the end line'
```

Results to a process crash without ever reaching the end line throwing this Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 17, in <module>
    func('a')
  File "test.py", line 12, in func
    raise ValueError('expected integer. receivd: %s instead'%type(arg))
ValueError: expected integer. receivd: <type 'str'> instead
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
```

I also would like to avoid `try` approach as well. Since it introduces more complexity to the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a function raises an exeption, whoever calls the function is responsible for catching any exception it may throw.

```
try:
    func(a)
except ValueError as e:
    print e
print "This is the end."
```

Or, alternatively, if you just want the exception to be printed as Python normally would, but still finish the script, use a `finally` clause:

```
try:
    func('a')
finally:
    print "This is the end."
```

(The exception traceback will be printed *after* the "This is the end message" from the script, somewhat counterintuitively.)

Comment: I was appending an edit to my original question that I would like to avoid using `try`... sorry I shouldn't be posting the question before completing it. I guess there is no other way to escape the function without using `try`.

Comment: So you want to use exceptions, but don't want to handle them. So, you're going to get what you get when you don't handle exceptions.

Comment: Is my use of `return` in place of exception would seem acceptable?

Comment: A function that returns more than one type of thing is a little confusing, and returning `None` in case of an error makes actually handling errors more difficult. Don't do it that way.

Comment: If you want to avoid `try`, you could return a tuple, with say the first value being the error code, and the second value being the actual return value.  This would not be pythonic as `try` `except` is the standard approach.

(With an error code of 0 meaning success)

Comment: Interesting, so the function should be designed to process the incoming argument without ever checking it? And the `try` exception handling should be placed at the line that calls the function?

Comment: Checking arguments is fine; giving more information to the person calling the function is better than giving them less information. Raise an exception if you get a value you can't handle.

Comment: But if we handle the Exception at the time we call the function there wouldn't be a need for the function to check the incoming argument for validity. Otherwise we end up 1: verifying the incoming argument inside of the function and 2: handling the `Exception`when we call the function. Should I just stick to one or another instead?

Comment: You might be able to get away without one or the other in your simple functions, but when you have more complexity (longer functions, and functions calling other functions, some of which you didn't write) it's nice to have more useful error messages. A "natural" `ValueError` that tells you `wook` and `fonk` can't be added isn't very useful when you didn't pass in any variables by that name to the function you called. If the function you called had validated its arguments you would know exactly what you did wrong. Fail fast.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return `None` when the argument is not an `int` then that's fine. As pointed in the comments this usually don't make much sense but we know nothing about the software this function is part of, so maybe in your case it does make sense.

`try`and `except` clauses were invented to help you to deal with exceptional situations at run time and they are quite good at it. If you think that calling your function with a non-integer value is something exceptional you'd probably better use `try` and `except`. If you think that your function should handle non-integers by returning `None` then your code is fine.